# Reading from FTP Server randomly returns a blank text file

Tags: c#, download, ftp, text-files

First, I did try to search for an answer for my problem but failed to find one.

I've been making a program in which my local text file and online text file, which is located in a FTP server, automatically updates each other. The text file contains list of names. This application was designed to be use by different machines simultaneously and can add and delete names in the list.

With the help of additional algorithm, I am able to merge the local and online text files without causing problems even when used offline and just update when there is an internet connection (using additional local files).

Now for the problem, everything works perfectly 90% of the time. However, sometimes the downloaded text file from the FTP server returns a blank text file even though it is not. I noticed that it is most likely to happen when my application is having a hard time checking for internet connection (Pinging google.com). This will result to a total erasure of the list since my application will interpret it as "The other user using the application deleted the list".

Here is the method I use to download from FTP server:

```
public Boolean DownloadFile(string uri, string path)
{
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.Timeout = 5000;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.username, this.password);
    try
    {
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FTPHANDLER DOWNLOAD FILE:"+e.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method I used for checking internet connection:

```
private static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            String host = "google.com";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
            int timeout = 15000;
            PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
            return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the way I call it. I've provided safety measures for that not to happen but it still occur.

```
public void Update()
{ 
  if(CheckForInternetConnection()){
     if (DownloadFile(uri,path))
     {
       char[] charsToTrim = { '\r', '\n' };
       string onlineFile = File.ReadAllText(path).TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
       if (onlineConfigFile.Equals("") || onlineConfigFile == null)
           MessageBox.Show("Downloaded file is empty");
       //still do stuff here regardless of the message
       //If the other user really do intend to delete the list
     }
   }
}
```

The update method is executed in a different thread.

As for my first post here, sorry that it turned out to be very long. I did try to make it short but didn't want to miss any details.

Comment: I'm looking at using "lock" now since the Update method is called every 5 secs  and each of them are ran in a different thread. This will ensure that the logic for the safety measure won't be exploited by other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the nature of my problem (random), I think the "lock" solution did the fix for me since the problem did not occur after I use it for quite some time now. It was maybe because of the threads, which are spawned every 5secs, that caused the problem where they are processing different parts of the method simultaneously.

Here is the fixed code:

```
public void Update()
{ 
  lock(lockObject)
  {
    if(CheckForInternetConnection())
    {
      if (DownloadFile(uri,path))
      {
        char[] charsToTrim = { '\r', '\n' };
        string onlineFile = File.ReadAllText(path).TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
        if (onlineConfigFile.Equals("") || onlineConfigFile == null)
          MessageBox.Show("Downloaded file is empty");
       //still do stuff here regardless of the message
       //If the other user really do intend to delete the list
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I declared "lockObject" as class level variable with a data type of "Object".